# batch query is not allowed to request data from "derivatives"."autogen"

Tags: influxdb, kapacitor

Good afternoon,
I have created the following tickscript with a standard tickstack setup.
Which includes: InfluxDB(latest version) and kapacitor(latest version):

```
dbrp "derivatives"."default"
var data = batch
|query('select sum(value) from "derivatives"."default".derivative_test where time > now() - 10m')
        .every(1m)
        .period(2m)

var slope = data
    |derivative('value')
        .as('slope')
        .unit(2m)

slope
    |eval(lambda: ("slope" - "value") / "value")
        .as('percentage')

    |alert()
        .crit(lambda: "percentage" <= -50)
        .id('derivative_test_crit')
        .message('{{ .Level }}: DERIVATIVE FOUND!')
        .topic('derivative')

// DEBUGGING
    |influxDBOut()
        .database('derivatives')
        .measurement('derivative_logs')
        .tag('sum', 'sum')
        .tag('slope', 'slope')
        .tag('percentage', 'percentage')
```

But every time i want to define it i get the following message:

```
batch query is not allowed to request data from "derivatives"."autogen"
```

I never had this problem before with `stream`'s but every `batch` tick script i write returns the same message.

My kapacitor user has full admin privs and i am able to get the data via a curl request, does anyone have any idea what could possibly be the problem here?

My thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Change this

```
dbrp "derivatives"."default"
var data = batch
|query('select sum(value) from "derivatives"."default".derivative_test where time > now() - 10m')
```

to this:

```
dbrp "derivatives"."autogen"
var data = batch
|query('select sum(value) from "derivatives"."autogen".derivative_test where time > now() - 10m')
```

It might not be obvious, but the retention policy is most likely incorrect.

If you run SHOW RETENTION POLICIES on the derivatives database you will see the RP's. I suspect you have an RP of autogen, which is the default RP. However "default" doesn't normally exist as an RP unless you create it, it just signifies that it is the default RP, if that makes sense?

RP Documentation might help clear it up [Database Documentation](https://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/v1.5/query_language/database_management/#retention-policy-management).

[default autogen RP](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XK0gv.png)