# batch query is not allowed to request data from "".""

Tags: ubuntu-18.04, influxdb, kapacitor

I'm getting started with Kapacitor and have been trying to run the [first guide](https://www.docs.influxdata.com/kapacitor/v1.5/guides/join_backfill/) in the Kapacitor documentation, but with data I already have. I managed to define a task, but I can neither enable it nor can I run a backfill. I came across [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49552705/5823275), which is similar to my problem, but the answer there didn't help. In contrast to the error message there I get empty strings for database, retention policy, and/or measurement.

In Kapacitor config I set an InfluxDB connection to the local host instance with the name `localhost` (which has a database `mydb` and the measurements `weather.current.clouds` and `weather.current.visibility` with default retention policy `autogen`) and created the following `weathertest.tick` script:

```
dbrp "mydb"."autogen"

var clouds = batch
  |query('select mean(value) / 100.0 as val from "mydb"."autogen"."weather.current.clouds"')
    .period(1h)
    .every(1h)
    .groupBy(time(1m), *)
    .fill(0)

var vis = batch
  |query('select mean(value) / 10000.0 as val from "mydb"."autogen"."weather.current.visibility"')
    .period(1h)
    .every(1h)
    .groupBy(time(1m), *)
    .fill(0)

clouds
  |join(vis)
    .as('c', 'v')
  |eval(lambda: 100 * (1 - "c.val") * "v.val")
    .as('pcent')
  |influxDBOut()
    .cluster('localhost')
    .database('mydb')
    .retentionPolicy('autogen')
    .measurement('testmetric')
    .tag('host', 'myhost.local')
    .tag('key', 'weather.current.lightidx')
```

This is what I came up with after hours of trial and (especially) error. As given in the title, when I try to enable my task with `kapacitor enable weathertest`, I get the error message `enabling task weathertest: batch query is not allowed to request data from "".""`. Same thing when I try to record as in the ["Backfill" example](https://www.docs.influxdata.com/kapacitor/v1.5/guides/join_backfill/#backfill). Also, in that example there is a start and a stop date for limiting the time frame. The time format given there is wrong and is not understood by Kapacitor. Instead of e. g. `2015-10-01` I have to put in `2015-10-01T00:00Z` to make it at least pass the error message regarding time format error.

In the Kapacitor logs there is not a single line regarding these errors, only when I try to remove a record, I get something like `remove /var/lib/kapacitor/replay/1f5...750.brpl: no such file or directory` and this can be found in the logs. There are lots of `info` lines in the logs showing successful POSTs to/from InfluxDB for the `_internal` database with HTTP response result 204.

**Has anyone an Idea what I may be doing wrong?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, after the weekend I tried again. Without any change it accepted my script now in the failing steps, however, now I was able to find error messages in the log. The node mentioned there was the `eval` node and pointed towards a type mismatch. When I changed the line

```
|eval(lambda: 100 * (1 - "c.val") * "v.val")
```

to

```
|eval(lambda: 100.0 * (1.0 - "c.val") * "v.val")
```

the error messages were gone and the command `kapacitor show weathertest` showed a rather sane content now.

Furthermore, I redefined, recorded, replayed and deleted the tasks and recordings during my tests over and over again and I may have forgotten to redefine tasks after making changes to the tick script (not really sure). After changing the above, redefining the task and replaying it I finally found the expected data in the InfluxDB instance.